# Bat File: Start iexplore, get html when loaded

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

I would like to start  IEXPLORE (or Firefox) in a process and collect the html from the page when it's loaded. Is this possible? I've been trying the following:

`start /d "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" FIREFOX.EXE http://www.example.com > html.txt`

`start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.example.com > html.txt`

EDIT: The connection I'm opening is persistent, so I want to leave the IEXPLORE process running to receive data asyncronously and so I'm just trying to get the html from the START process that was opened by the batch file.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: iMacro is a Firefox addon that may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm):

```
wget -O html.txt www.google.com
```

Please note the uppercase letter `O`.

Comment: I can't use wget as I need the connection to remain open. The example above is just a simple one. The connection is persistent, so I need to just collect the html, use it for something else, and leave the persistent connection open. I've added some detail to the question above.